# rake db:migrate rake aborted! NoMethodEr

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

When I try to run *rake db:migrate* I am getting following error:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: The factory_girl gem is deprecated. Please upgrade to factory_bot. See https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/v4.9.0/UPGRADE_FROM_FACTORY_GIRL.md for further instructions. (called from <top (required)> at /var/www/html/sophy_web/config/application.rb:14)
/root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_type.rb:163: warning: already initialized constant Mime::PDF
/root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_type.rb:163: warning: previous definition of PDF was here
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass
/var/www/html/application/config/initializers/rollbar.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/var/www/html/application/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I am using ruby version 2.5.1 and rails 4.2.8.

Code of my rollbar.rb:

```
require 'rollbar/rails'
Rollbar.configure do |config|      
  config.access_token = '9234902384023843203fsd23'

  # Here we'll disable in 'test':
  if Rails.env.test?
    config.enabled = false
  end
end
```

Code of my environment.rb

```
# Load the Rails application.
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Initialize the Rails application.
Rails.application.initialize!
```

Comment: check your rollbar file, 2nd line, better if you include that code in your question

Comment: well, can't find anything uncommon in that file...

Comment: yes my bad, reading the log, `NoMethodError: undefined method '>' for nil:NilClass` says you're calling `>` on nil

Comment: yes, but I'm not sure where it makes the call to `>`

Comment: The only thing you can do is debug, because without looking at code its hard to solve it

Comment: Did you try running rake with the --trace argument as suggested? It may show more backtrace helping you to locate the place where > is called.

Comment: yes, without success.

Comment: Since you didn't write it explicitly is assume (correct me if I'm wrong):
1. you did `bundle install` after adding `Rollbar` to your `Gemfile`
2. you did also add `gem 'oj'`
3. you did `(bundle exec) rails generate rollbar POST_SERVER_ITEM_ACCESS_TOKEN`

Comment: Just a side note, you should use an env variable for you Rollbar token (instead of just putting it there in `rollbar.rb`)

Comment: @JaySchneider thanks for your help. It did not solve my problem but after removing rollbar everything works fine. Will integrate rollbar later. Thank you